# New line when using fopen to write text

Tags: php, file-io, fopen

Simple question. I am appending entries into a text file, and I want to have each new entry on the next line. As it stands here, the subsequent entries are printed after the last. What do I enter to write each entry on a new line? Using Windows.

```
$fh = fopen($dir . '/' . "Cause.txt", 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $affiliation . "\n");
fclose($fh);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They already are. Use a text editor better than Notepad to view the file, or print out `"\r\n"` instead.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Amazing. Thanks for pointing that out. Opened with jEdit.